# Why this simple query is failing in a mule flow?

Tags: sql, oracle, mule, mule-el, anypoint-studio

I have to make some changes in a existing mule flow with little knowledge and although I've spent some days reading online documentation and possible solutions to this, I cannot figure out why this query is failing, as I also have more dynamic queries in my flow with #[xxx] parameters. The query is as follows:

```
select times from user_request where 
ip_address=SUBSTR(#message.inboundProperties.MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS],2,INSTR(#[message.inboundProperties.MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS], ':')-2) 
    and request_date=CAST(CURRENT_DATE as varchar2(8))
```

And the error I got is:

> Message               : Index: 0
>   (java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException). Payload               :
>   {fecha_solicitud=2016-06-22, moneda=USD, client_id=RIVERA,
>   user_ip=127.0.0.1, request_times=0} Payload Type          :
>   java.util.LinkedHashMap Element               :
>   /OANDAFlow/processors/3 @ oanda:oanda.xml:126 Element XML           :
>    
>   select times from user_requestwhere
>   ip_address=SUBSTR(#[message.inboundProperties.MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS],2,INSTR(#[message.inboundProperties.MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS],
>   ':')-2)and request_date=CAST(CURRENT_DATE as
>   varchar2(8))>

Note: The transformation to varchar of the date is because the column request_date is varchar.

I've tried this query directly in the Oracle SQL developer replacing       `#[message.inboundProperties.MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS]`
with and example like `/127.0.0.1:55406` and it worked fine so why through mule is failing???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the fields in your query expects a **string value** try to put a single quote..it would work ,

Try this 

`select times from user_request where 
ip_address=SUBSTR('#message.inboundProperties.MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS]',2,'INSTR(#[message.inboundProperties.MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS]', ':')-2) 
    and request_date=CAST(CURRENT_DATE as varchar2(8))`

Answer (score 3):

In the first: **#m**essage.inboundProperties.MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS] you are missing a **[**

Comment: Actually I had the bracket in the code, I don't know if the copy paste I did got transformed by this page editor... Thanks in any case!